# Submitting multiple values in php to a search query

Tags: php

I'm sorry I'm asking something very basic but I'm beyond stuck. I have a search form with 3 fields: a blank field for search term data, a dropdown box, and a checkbox list. My page is functioning as intended for the search term box.

However, I don't know what I need to do to be able to send the select value (one select choice) and checkbox values to the processing form.

This is my current query:

```
 SELECT nameid, productypetid, typeid, termsid, endsid, sourceid FROM listings WHERE nameid LIKE %s ORDER BY nameid ASC
```

This is the html form:

```
<form action="results2.php" method="get" name="form" class="Ccenter">
<p>Product Name: 
<input name="namesearch" type="text" id="namesearch" title="namesearch" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="category">Category:</label>
<select name="category" size="1" id="category">
  <option value="Any" selected="selected">Any</option>
  <option value="Baby and Kids">Baby and Kids</option>
  <option value="Beauty and Hair">Beauty and Hair</option>
  <option value="Beverages">Beverages</option>
  <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
  <option value="Condiments">Condiments</option>
  <option value="Cooking and Baking">Cooking and Baking</option>
  <option value="Dairy">Dairy</option>
  <option value="Frozen">Frozen</option>
  <option value="Meat">Meat</option>
  <option value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  <option value="Pantry Foods">Pantry Foods</option>
  <option value="Paper Products">Paper Products</option>
  <option value="Pets">Pets</option>
  <option value="Restaurants">Restaurants</option>
  <option value="Snacks and Candy">Snacks and Candy</option>
  <option value="Toiletries">Toiletries</option>
</select>
</p>
   <p>
    <label>
     Type:
    <input name="Type" type="checkbox" id="manufacturer" value="manufacturer"     checked="checked">
  Manufacturer</label>
<label>
  <input name="Type" type="checkbox" id="store" value="store" checked="checked">
  Store</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing the namesearch text field like so:

```
$name = $_GET['namesearch'];
```

Then your category select field will be available via:

```
$category = $_GET['category'];
```

As for your checkboxes (manufacturer and store), they may or may not exist in the $_GET array. It depends on whether the user has checked them or not.

```
$manufacturer = isset($_GET['manufacturer']) ? $manufacturer : null;
$store = isset($_GET['store']) ? $store: null;
```

Comment: You mean `$_GET` since his form method is `GET`